# Using IF software in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

I have Xubuntu 9.04 running in our old machine at home. I'm looking to run some interactive fiction interpreters such as [Frobtads](http://tads.org/frobtads.htm) there as well. However, it appears most of the Linux versions of the general IF software are in source form. Pre-compiled binaries are usually available either for Windows users or for other versions of Linux (Debian, etc.).

Do I generally need to compile these if it's only available in source form? What considerations should I keep in mind when doing so?

N.B.: Please provide as much detail as possible. I'm still exploring how to use most of Xubuntu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to find the `.deb` and `.rpm` packages. On the Frobtads page they provide a link for you to [this website](http://ifiction.free.fr/index.php?id=iflinux).

You will also want to [search the Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). Packages you find on there can be installed using apt like so:

```
sudo apt-get install package_name
```

of course, replacing `package_name` appropriately.

Comment: From what I understand, I download them, apt-get any dependencies (required files), then unpack them. Is that it?

Comment: you can use apt to install the entire program if it's in the repos. If you find a .deb file you can simply open terminal and use `dpkg -i file.deb`

Comment: Thanks. Finally got it working. +1 for the Ubuntu packages link to the other games as well. :)